# Java- User Array outside of Event Listener

Tags: java, arrays, event-handling

I can't figure out a way to use an Array(in this case containerinput[]) outide of the event listener it is in.

In the event listener i generate textfields, inputfields and so on, and outside of it i want to make a keylistener that when the last input field is selected and i press tab i want something to happen.

Everything works find except that i cant call the array because its outside of the scope and i cant figure a way to change that :( This is the event the array is in:

```
JPanel zusatzPanel = new JPanel();
zusatzPanel.setBounds(11, 291, 270, 113);
contentPane2.add(zusatzPanel);
zusatzPanel.setLayout(null);

int[] ZusatzpanelCase = new int [300];
ZusatzpanelCase[1] = 0;

comboBox_projekt.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        zusatzPanel.removeAll();    
        for(int key = 0; key < ObjektlängeForActionListener; key++){
            if(comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem() == null){
                zusatzPanel.removeAll();    
                zusatzPanel.revalidate();
                zusatzPanel.repaint();
                break;
            }else{
                if(comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem().equals(Projektname0JSON[key])){
                    zusatzPanel.removeAll();    
                    zusatzPanel.revalidate();
                    zusatzPanel.repaint();

                    String ZusatzString;
                    try {
                        ZusatzString = SimplePingPong.httpRequestZusatz(ProjektPK0JSON[key],"unused","zusatz");
                        if(ZusatzString.equals("Keine Werte")){
                            ZusatzpanelCase[1] = 0;

                        }else{  
                            JSONObject jsonObjectZusatz = new JSONObject(ZusatzString); 
                            int ZusatzJSONlength = jsonObjectZusatz.length();
                            int xValue = 0;
                            JTextField[] containerinput = new JTextField[ZusatzJSONlength];
                            JComboBox[] containerselect = new JComboBox[ZusatzJSONlength];
                            JLabel[] containerlabel = new JLabel[ZusatzJSONlength];

                            for(int key1 = 0; key1 < ZusatzJSONlength; key1++){
                                JSONObject jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0 = jsonObjectZusatz.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(key1));  
                                String ZusatzNameJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("name");  // String auslesen!!!
                                String ZusatzTypJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("typ");  // String auslesen!!!
                                String ZusatzEintragJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("eintrag");  // String auslesen!!!

;


                                                    if(ZusatzTypJSON.equals("input")){
                                    containerinput[key1] = new JTextField();
                                    containerinput[key1].setBounds(108, xValue, 136, 20);
                                    zusatzPanel.add(containerinput[key1]);
                                    containerinput[key1].setColumns(10);
                                }
                                if(ZusatzTypJSON.equals("select")){
                                    containerselect[key1] = new JComboBox();
                                    containerselect[key1].setBounds(108, xValue, 136, 20);
                                    zusatzPanel.add(containerselect[key1]);
                                }
                                containerlabel[key1] = new JLabel(ZusatzNameJSON);
                                containerlabel[key1].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                                containerlabel[key1].setBounds(1, xValue + 1, 100, 15);
                                zusatzPanel.add(containerlabel[key1]);

                                ZusatzpanelCase[1] = 1;
                                ZusatzpanelCase[2] = ZusatzpanelCase[2] + 1;

                                xValue = xValue + 30;
                                zusatzPanel.revalidate();
                                zusatzPanel.repaint();
                            } 




                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } 



                }

            }
        }


    }
 });
```

and here i want to make the key listener:

```
containerinput[ZusatzpanelCase[2]].setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); 
containerinput[ZusatzpanelCase[2]].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB){
                String dauervar = input_dauer.getText ();  //auslesen von benutzername
                String beschreibungvar = textArea_beschreibung.getText ();  //auslesen von benutzername
                String projektvar = (String)comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem();
                String aktivitvar = (String)comboBox_aktivitaet.getSelectedItem();

                String datumvar = input_datum.getText ();  
                SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = df1.parse(datumvar);
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                long epoch = date.getTime();
                String numberAsStringUnixTImestamp = String.valueOf(epoch / 1000);

                String [ ] datenarray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};  

                datenarray[0] = numberAsStringUnixTImestamp;
                datenarray[1] = dauervar;   
                datenarray[2] = beschreibungvar;    
                datenarray[3] = projektvar; 
                datenarray[4] = aktivitvar; 
                datenarray[5] = usernamevar;    

                String JsonArray = "{ \"" + "datum" + "\":\"" + datenarray[0] + "\", \"" + "dauer" + "\":\"" + datenarray[1] + "\", \"" + "beschreibung" + "\":\"" + datenarray[2] + "\", \"" + "projektname" + "\":\"" + datenarray[3] + "\", \"" + "kategorie" + "\":\"" + datenarray[4] + "\", \"" + "username" + "\":\"" + datenarray[5] + "\" }";
                System.out.println(JsonArray);

                input_datum.setText(reportDate);
                if(check_datum.isSelected()){
                    CustomDateFinal[0] = datumvar;
                    input_datum.setText(CustomDateFinal[0]);

                }                               
                input_dauer.setText(USERDefTimeJSON);
                textArea_beschreibung.setText("");
                comboBox_projekt.requestFocus();


                try {
                    SimplePingPong.httpRequestVoid(JsonArray,"unused","werte");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

    }
});
```

How can i make my containerinput[] visible outside or is there a workaround.

Thanks beforehand :)

Comment: Where you want to access `containerinput[]`? Is it outside the `class` ? or whithin the `class` but outside the `method` in same `class` ?

Comment: It is outside the event handler in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your `containerinput` array outside the event handler e.g. on class level and initialize them inside your event handler.

**Your Updated code Example**

```
JPanel zusatzPanel = new JPanel();
zusatzPanel.setBounds(11, 291, 270, 113);
contentPane2.add(zusatzPanel);
zusatzPanel.setLayout(null);

JTextField[] containerinput; //like that
JComboBox[] containerselect; //like that
JLabel[] containerlabel;     //like that

int[] ZusatzpanelCase = new int [300];
ZusatzpanelCase[1] = 0;

comboBox_projekt.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        zusatzPanel.removeAll();    
        for(int key = 0; key < ObjektlängeForActionListener; key++){
            if(comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem() == null){
                zusatzPanel.removeAll();    
                zusatzPanel.revalidate();
                zusatzPanel.repaint();
                break;
            }else{
                if(comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem().equals(Projektname0JSON[key])){
                    zusatzPanel.removeAll();    
                    zusatzPanel.revalidate();
                    zusatzPanel.repaint();

                    String ZusatzString;
                    try {
                        ZusatzString = SimplePingPong.httpRequestZusatz(ProjektPK0JSON[key],"unused","zusatz");
                        if(ZusatzString.equals("Keine Werte")){
                            ZusatzpanelCase[1] = 0;

                        }else{  
                            JSONObject jsonObjectZusatz = new JSONObject(ZusatzString); 
                            int ZusatzJSONlength = jsonObjectZusatz.length();
                            int xValue = 0;
                            containerinput = new JTextField[ZusatzJSONlength];
                            containerselect = new JComboBox[ZusatzJSONlength];
                            containerlabel = new JLabel[ZusatzJSONlength];

                            for(int key1 = 0; key1 < ZusatzJSONlength; key1++){
                                JSONObject jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0 = jsonObjectZusatz.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(key1));  
                                String ZusatzNameJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("name");  // String auslesen!!!
                                String ZusatzTypJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("typ");  // String auslesen!!!
                                String ZusatzEintragJSON = jsonObjectZusatzObjekt0.getString("eintrag");  // String auslesen!!!

;


                                                    if(ZusatzTypJSON.equals("input")){
                                    containerinput[key1] = new JTextField();
                                    containerinput[key1].setBounds(108, xValue, 136, 20);
                                    zusatzPanel.add(containerinput[key1]);
                                    containerinput[key1].setColumns(10);
                                }
                                if(ZusatzTypJSON.equals("select")){
                                    containerselect[key1] = new JComboBox();
                                    containerselect[key1].setBounds(108, xValue, 136, 20);
                                    zusatzPanel.add(containerselect[key1]);
                                }
                                containerlabel[key1] = new JLabel(ZusatzNameJSON);
                                containerlabel[key1].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                                containerlabel[key1].setBounds(1, xValue + 1, 100, 15);
                                zusatzPanel.add(containerlabel[key1]);

                                ZusatzpanelCase[1] = 1;
                                ZusatzpanelCase[2] = ZusatzpanelCase[2] + 1;

                                xValue = xValue + 30;
                                zusatzPanel.revalidate();
                                zusatzPanel.repaint();
                            } 




                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } 



                }

            }
        }


    }
 });
```

Now you can access then anywhere within `class`.

Comment: i get the error: Local variable containerinput defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final. it doesnt change if i set it final..

Answer (score 0):

You want it to be visible outside, so why don't you define it outside and not inside of listener?

Define it there where you already have this:

```
JPanel zusatzPanel = new JPanel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `containerinput` a private member of your class (declare it outside of any Class function).

It will then be available to the class methods (only).

You can control visibility of containerinput outside of the class using `protected` or `public` modifiers:

- `protected` will make it visible to subclasses and other classes in the same package.
- `public` will make it visible to every class.

Comment: i cant do this because i need it to have a certain length and i only have access to this length inside the event handler sadly

Comment: Use an ArrayList if you don't know the length at class initialization. it can grow dynamically and you can query the length with .size()